# NextJS middleware no cookie sent to the NestJS backend

Tags: next.js, cookies, nestjs, middleware

I'm using NextJS as my frontend and NestJS as my backend, I'm trying to check if the session id is valid, i'm sending a request inside my NextJS middleware to my backend, the request is reaching my backend, but when i try to access the cookies in my backend with req.cookies, it gives me this [Object: null prototype] {}. When i send the very same request but from a normal page like the homepage, it sends the cookies normally, so the problem seems to be in the middleware.

My NextJS middleware

```
// middleware.ts
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.cookies.has("userData")) {
    let cookie = request.cookies.get("userData");

    console.log(cookie);

    fetch(new URL("/authentication/check-auth", "http://localhost:5000"), {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};
```

My NestJS main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import helmet from "helmet";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const corsOptions: any = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors(corsOptions);
  app.use(helmet());
  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```

My NestJS Controller.ts

```
 @Get("check-auth")
  async checkAuth(@Req() req: Request) {
    try {
      const cookies = req.cookies;
      console.log("Cookies:", cookies); //Cookies: [Object: null prototype] {}

      const result = await this.authenticationService.checkAuth(cookies);

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      return { error: "An error occurred" };
    }
  }
```

My NestJS Service.ts

```
async checkAuth(sessionID: any) {
    const exists = await this.redisClient.exists(sessionID.userData);
    console.log(exists);
    return exists === 1;
  }
```

My Cookie in the application tab of my browser
[image: my cookie]